# GTK3 theme wanted with close button on top right pixel

Tags: gnome, themes, gtk

I am looking for a GTK3 theme for the gnome desktop which allows the following use case:

> To close a maximized window, one can move the mouse to the pixel at
>   the very top right corner of the screen and press the left mouse
>   button.

Of course, this can only work if you do not have a top panel.

The problem with most GTK themes is that their close button (even if positioned on the top right corner of a maximized window) is not on the top right pixel of the screen. Some themes even use rounded buttons, which do not cover the top right pixel for obvious reasons.

Using metacity themes, the desired effect is provided by the `Human` theme (https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/human-theme). Unfortunately, not all windows use the metacity theme.

Any suggestions for a GTK3 theme with the described behavior are welcome, though clean and simple themes (such as `Human`) would be preferable.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? I think Ubuntu 18.04 now has the window manager (Mutter) built into GNOME Shell. And the window manager theme, controlling decorations such as the close button, would be distinct from the GTK theme.

Comment: By the way, the use of a top panel possibly made people less mindful about [Fitts's Law](https://lawsofux.com/fittss-law)! I use "Alt+Spacebar, C" to close windows rather than have to place my mouse pointer exactly over the close button. In KDE Plasma, I've set Win+C to do the same thing.

Comment: I use Ubuntu 18.04 with gnome-session-flashback. Some applications such as the gnome-terminal use the metacity theme, but for example evince does use the GTK theme.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure if I am going to stick with this theme, but [Marwaita](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1239855/) does the job.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/923993)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but in my opinion the name of the theme "Marwaita" is essentially the answer. I only included the link to make it easier to find.

Comment: @KristopherIves OP is correct. **Voted to leave open**

Comment: Sorry for the misflag.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is GTK issue, not GTK theme issue. See this https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/issues/583

As you can see there, the behavior that you want sometimes works, e.g. in Firefox, and LibreOffice and sometimes it does not, e.g. in Nautilus or Evince.